# How to dynamically resolve nodejs required module's path based on caller script's path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am kind of new to Javascript programming. Currently I am trying to write a test for Javascript files in existing codebase that contains other programming languages. The structure is like below.

```
src/js/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/
    Rectangle.jsx
    Circle.jsx
test/js/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/
    RectangleTest.jsx
    CircleTest.jsx
```

The content of `RectangleTest.jsx` is below

```
import Rectangle from './../../../../../../../src/js/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/Rectangle';

describe('<Rectangle>', () => {
    it('Should show content', () => {
        assert.ok(true);
    });
});
```

As you can see, I need to set the path as a very long relative path `./../../../../../../../src/js/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5`. It will be very exhaustive for I prefer something like below.

```
import Rectangle from './Rectangle';
```

Since the path of the test file and the tested file is pretty similar, it should be possible to calculate the path to be resolved by the import.

Is there a way to do that?

I am using `mocha` for the testing framework. I uploaded the sample code to Github ([link](https://github.com/petrabarus/js-test-with-java-file-structure/tree/3976f1030a5fa836d0bf5881209a806e4e07ead8)), so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching about how nodejs resolve module, it turns out that it's possible to override the `require` function behavior by overriding `module` module.

So I write a file called `bootstrap.js` that contains code below

```
let path = require('path');
const BASE_DIR = __dirname;
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(BASE_DIR + '/../../src/js');
var Module = require('module');
Module.prototype.require = new Proxy(Module.prototype.require, {
    apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList){
        let name = argumentsList[0];
        let isLocal = thisArg.filename.startsWith(BASE_DIR) &&
            name.startsWith('./');
        if (isLocal) {
            let testFileDir = path.dirname(thisArg.filename)
            let testPath = testFileDir.replace(BASE_DIR, '');
            let srcPath = SRC_DIR + testPath;
            let relativePath = path.relative(testFileDir, srcPath);
            argumentsList[0] = relativePath + '/' + name;
        }
        return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList)
    }
});
```

The structure now is like this

```
src/js/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/
    Rectangle.jsx
    Circle.jsx
test/js/
    bootstrap.js
    path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/
       RectangleTest.jsx
       CircleTest.jsx
```

To execute the test, I use the statement below

```
nyc mocha --recursive \
    --require test/js/bootstrap.js \
    --compilers js:babel-core/register \
    test/js/**/*.{js,jsx}
```

Using the code above, I can check the caller script and called module and see if the caller script resides in the `test` directory. If it does then, it will see if the module called by using relative path.

The advantage is that, we still can use `import` statement.

```
import Rectangle from './Rectangle';

describe('<Rectangle>', () => {
    it('Should show content', () => {
        assert.ok(true);
    });
});
```

The downside is for now the test file cannot call relative path in the test directory. Relative path will now only resolve in source path. But it's good for now. I am wondering if we can check if a module is resolvable or not.

The updated source code can be read [here](https://github.com/petrabarus/js-test-with-java-file-structure/tree/19bc220596a0cb3e4fde7d3821d44666e15d2187).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__dirname` global node variable which contains the absolute path to the current file. However you have to use `require()` instead of `import ...` because import does not support dynamic paths.

if your absolute path only contains one test name you can get away with:

```
const path = require('path');
const retanglePath = path.join(__dirname.replace('/test/', '/src/'), 'Rectangle'));
const Rectangle = require(rectanglePath).default;
```

Note: the `.default` is for ES6 exports that are converted with babel.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Here is a solution that also works with other test folder names in the absolute path (replace the path relative for your needs):

```
const path = require('path');
const basePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../');
const srcPath = __dirname.replace(basePath + 'test', basePath + 'src');
const Rectangle = require(path.join(srcPath, 'Rectangle')).default;
```